# How do I get the height of a string in PDFBox?

Tags: java, pdfbox

I want to center a block of text in a rectangle. I am currently using the `PDFont.getStringWidth` method for centering horizontally. However, I do not see a corresponding `PDFont.getStringHeight` method. Is there a way to get the height of a string, taking into account descenders? I see the `getHeight` method, but that would only work for a single character, and sounds like it would be expensive to call for a long string.

Comment: What version are you using, and what font type are you using, and how do you define "height"? It's easy for an "a", but for a "g" there are two different answers. However there is no "getstringheight()" method, you'll have to calculate for each character by getting the path. So it's quite tricky.

Comment: To see how tricky it is to get a glyph height, have a look at the DrawPrintTextLocations.java example in the source code download (calculateGlyphBounds method).

Comment: @TilmanHausherr we're using PDFBox 2.x. Height for this case means the height of the bounding box of all text. I'd like to take into account any kerning, which precludes me from measuring each glyph individually.

Comment: PDFBox doesn't do kerning. So what you'd need is the highest height of all glyphs. And for that I need the font type (type1, truetype, type0) you're using. If you look at the code mentioned, you'll see that each type has a different strategy.